# "::before" disappearing when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following line of code:

```
<a href="##" class="navbar-toggle pull-left js-tray-toggle"><span class="icon-menu"></span></a>

.icon-menu:before {
content: "\e001";
}


*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

when I resize the browser to a tablet dimension (tested as well on real devices) the "::before" disappears inside the span element making the icon not displaying on tablets.

The font-icon generated disappears when you are in tablets but it's fine on mobiles. When inspected the ":before" disappears when the window is resized at an average tablet dimension and then it appears again in a mobile dimension.

Comment: Are you using a frontend library such as Bootstrap?

Comment: Can you reproduce on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64MY3/)?

Comment: Can you confirm that there isn't any media query CSS involved?

Comment: Hi yes, I am using twitter boostrap and there are no media queries that I can see in the inspector

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue